# Delete recursively created folders in windows 7

Tags: windows

In my code in accidental created folder inside folder for more than 1000 times in different places. The folder tu will contain tu which will contain tu and so on. I fixed the issue in my code but the folder is still persist in my file system.

When I tried to delete it, it is showing **error::source file names are larger than is supported, try moving to location of shorter path r try renaming to shorter name**

Comment: Did you try DOS command RMDIR /S?

Comment: Check answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/718224/393207)

Comment: T:\Chandru\Working_IKST\build-Cascade-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug>rmd
ir /S t1
t1, Are you sure (Y/N)? Y
t1\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2
\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t
2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2\t2 - The directory is not empty.

Comment: it is not deleted the directory . giving this error

Comment: [This should work.](http://superuser.com/a/818993/96662)